# How to take place name resolution. net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error is occurred, when using docker compose and docker network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How to take place name resolution. net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error is occurred, when using docker compose and docker network

Hello.

When I use docker compose and docker network to create frontend server and backend server and db server, `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` is occurred in google chrome console.

Below file is my `docker-compose.yml`.
I assured that the communication of backend-container to frontend-container is no problem, because I attached to frontend-container ( using command of `docker exec -it frontend-container /bin/bash`) and confirmed communication ( using command of `curl backend-container:4000`).
However, when I attempted to communicate backend-container from web browser (frontend application), `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` is occurred in chrome developer console.

I think that name resolution is not taking place from web browser.
However I have no idea how to name resolution in this case.

Please help me and teach me how to resolve name in this case.
Thank you.

```yaml
version: "3.5"
services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: "./project01_frontend"
      dockerfile: "Dockerfile.prod"
    container_name: frontend-container
    restart: always
    tty: true
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    env_file:
      - "./project01_frontend/.env"
    depends_on:
      - "db"
      - "backend"
  backend:
    build:
      context: "./project01_backend"
      dockerfile: "Dockerfile.dev"
    container_name: backend-container
    restart: always
    tty: true
    expose:
      - "4000"
    env_file:
      - "./project01_backend/.env"
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    command: ["./wait-for-db-container.sh", "yarn", "start"]
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.34
    command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    container_name: db-container
    volumes:
      - ./project01_backend/initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "typeorm_db"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "password"
      TZ: "Asia/Tokyo"
    restart: "always"
    expose:
      - "3306"
```

Comment: If you're seeing that error message in the Chrome console, that means the application code is running in the browser.  The browser isn't in a container (and may not even be on the same host) and can't see the Docker container names.

Comment: @DavidMaze 
Thank you your comment.
I understand that you said. 
Does this mean that it is impossible to put them together in a docker network like in this docker-compose.yml?
Do I have to add the port code to the backend-container (`port 4000:4000`) and set the api destination of the frontend-container to `localhost:4000`?
I think this is a possible solution, but I would like to keep it within one docker network if possible.
Please let me know if this is possible.
Thank you much.

Comment: The browser will never be on a Docker network, and you have to use a published port for this case.